# How to fix docker-compose no such image latest when this image is not being used?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an issue i'd really like some help with. Been driving me mad.

`docker-compose up -d` with the `docker-compose.yml` contents below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: "public.ecr.aws/docker/library/mysql:5.7"
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=example
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db-init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

when running this i get the error:

```
No such image: public.ecr.aws/docker/library/mysql:latest
```

but i didn't ask for latest. bit stumped any ideas?

I tried to run docker-compose in a specific environment and despite not referencing latest it seems to try and reference it and then errors because of it.

Comment: I see this error as well, all the time. Here, it happens when I last used (with docker run) a multi-platform image for some other platform. Any time you switch platforms (with docker pull, docker run) it will output a line about latest not found even if you never asked for latest.  And worse, the first time you try it fails (but updates the local image registry) and the second time it succeeds.